# Nginx redirect cuts off part of the URL

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I am trying to redirect all requests to use https. I followed a lot of examples but no matter what I do the redirected URL seems to be missing part of the url.

```html
    server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     subdomain.mydomain.com;
        return          301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {

        listen       443 ssl;
        #server_name  localhost;
        server_name     subdomain.mydomain.com;

        root    /var/www/html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/certificate.key;

        ...

     }
```

This is the result on the nginx log:

```html
99.9.99.99 - blah@mydomain.com [15/Jan/2015:18:35:23 +0000] "GET /Organizer/footer.html HTTP/1.1" 301 184 "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/Organizer/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36" "999.999.9.999"
```

It cuts off the footer.html part of the request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What format do you use in logs? I guess it's a referer, not a redirect url.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's just the default nginx log.

Comment: Well, in that case how do you know it redirects wrong?

Comment: I guess I am assuming that the log shows where it's redirecting.

Comment: 301 184 "http://subdomain.mydomain.com/Organizer/"

Comment: Default log format contains http referer header.

Comment: OK so maybe the issue is something else. Do you see anything wrong with the way I have the redirect set up?

Comment: I would use $host instead of $server_name, but otherwise it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @AlexeyTen I tried using $host instead of $server_name and it still doesn't seem to work. It seems like the application has links with http:// and when you click on them they don't redirect :-/